How can I pass state when calling navigate(-1) with react-router-dom
If I do something like this in an onClick handler:
navigate('/some/route', {state: {foo: 'bar'}})

I can access foo in the component that mounts at /some/route like so:
const location = useLocation()
const {foo} = location.state

However,
foo is undefined if I do this:
navigate(-1, {state: {foo: 'bar'}})

The problem is that I need to use navigate(-1)for a custom back button, and I need to pass that state to know that the back button was clicked. Is there a way to pass state when value of the to param is -1
Thank you.
